# permission denied for config oh my posh on wsl

Tags: permissions, wsl2, windows-terminal

I tried to config **oh my posh** on [windows terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) (wsl ubunto 20.04)

Based on the [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup) , I run this command on wsl:

`wget https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/releases/latest/download/posh-linux-amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh`

but I encountered  **`permission denied`** error.

also I opened `/usr/local/bin` on file explorer and try to paste a file on `/usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh` but there too encountered permission denied.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to do this as yourself?

Comment: I am going to guess that `/usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh` was not actually created, but just as a sanity check, can you provide the permissions on that folder if it does exist as an edit to your question?

Comment: IMO, the Microsoft docs look wrong here.  `/usr/local/bin` should always be owned by root, and your normal user shouldn't have write permissions.  So `Permission denied` is the expected output.  I think the first set of commands need to be run with `sudo` or as the root user.  I'll give this a test in a throwaway WSL instance.

Comment: Of course, to be fair, Microsoft seems to just be copying the instructions from the Oh-my-posh [doc](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/).

Comment: I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/issues/654) on the oh-my-posh doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installation instructions are in error.  `/usr/local/bin` is always a root-owned directory to which a normal user will not have write permissions.  `Permission denied` is the correct output in this case.

Just run the first two commands as `sudo`:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/releases/latest/download/posh-linux-amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh
```

The rest of the installation instructions can be run as the default user, but note that `unzip` is not included by default in the WSL Ubuntu install, so you may need to install it with:

```
sudo apt install unzip
```

Alternative (not that it's needed) -- Start with `wsl -u root`, run these commands, and then exit and come back in as the normal user.